# directive is not getting applied on ng-repeat elements in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

am adding this below directive to my view(in html) in angularjs, it seems, am able to see the console.log on the console, but, the class 'subPlaylistSecondaryItemRemoval' is not being added.

my html

```
<ul class="dupeAssets" first-element-list>
     <li ng-repeat="dupeAssetslist in playlistAssets.assets track by $index" ng-if="dupeAssetslist.type == 'Playlist'">{{dupeAssetslist.title}}</li>
     </ul>
```

and my directive is below

```
 appModule.directive("firstElementList", function () {
        console.log("firstElementList");
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                $scope.$watch(element.children(), function () {
                    var children = element.children();
                    for (var i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
                        if (children[i].nodeType !== 8) {
                            angular.element(children[i]).addClass('subPlaylistSecondaryItemRemoval');
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

but,am getting the following error

```
angular.js:12783 ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

Any help please?

Comment: is it scope or $scope? May be a typo?

Comment: Yes that is because your scope is not `$scope`, but `scope`.

Comment: i tried both, but, both ways am getting the same error

Comment: Can you update the question with what you tried? We are expecting   you to update '$scope.$watch(element.children(), function () { ' line to 'scope.$watch(element.children(), function () {'

Comment: I tried with $scope.$watch and scope.$watch, if I use, scope.$watch, no error is coming, but, my aim is 'subPlaylistSecondaryItemRemoval' should be added to all elements inside 'ul' except first item i mean except frist list item, this is not happening, when i am using scope.$watch

Answer (score 0):

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
```

should be:

```
link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
working fiddel https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25262/
```

this fiddel use angular 1.0.3 so i removed track by index

Comment: working fiddle for your second problem: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25263/

        scope.$watch(element.children(), function() {
          var children = element.children();
          for (var i = 2; i < children.length; i++) {
              angular.element(children[i]).addClass('subPlaylistSecondaryItemRemoval');
          }
        });